# What is the fingering for the measure (or bar) 65 of this version of Memories of Lightwaves?

Tags: piano, fingering

I have been working on this song and I've got to a point where I am stuck.

On the beginning of measure (bar) 65 on the treble clef there are two notes that are super far apart.

Someone can point out what's the trick?

https://musescore.com/user/137385/scores/164512#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to imitate Wolfgang Mozart and play the middle part with your nose, there is no possible way to play this as notated (i.e. without noticeable arpeggio). It's simply a really bad error in this piano arrangement.

Comment: I wonder if the composer or arranger was imagining another instrument playing that middle voice.

Comment: It's a possibility. I will move on not considering the right hand low notes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a gesture of it and arpeggiating the two notes in the RH. Gesturally it should work if you do a little rit from the three previous quavers. There are plenty of pieces in which chords which have to be split aren't notated as such, for a few reasons:

1. In an arrangement like this, perhaps originally the notes weren't supposed to be.
2. It is assumed the player will split them anyway.
3. Laziness/oversight/lack of ability on the part of the arranger(s)/typesetter(s).

I don't know which of those it is for this, but I can almost guarantee you are supposed to spread them. (You can then take the rest of that second voice in the left hand.)

Hope this helps!